# lstinline - source code

Tags: listings

I want to use `\lstinline` for displaying inline source code in text. This code can contain various characters from different programming languages. For example

```
while{$a || $b}
```

This text doesn't work in any of these forms because it contains start/end character of lstinline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    % works
    \lstinline|while{$a && $b}|

    % doesn't work
    \lstlinline{while{$a || $b}}
    \lstlinline|while{$a || $b}|
    \lstlinline$while{$a || $b}$
\end{document}
```

I am looking for universal solution for multiple languages so there are many characters I can't use in this case (!, ^, ., {, |, etc...).

Is that possible with lstinline? If not, is there any good alternative? Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post fragments only -- any use willing to help you has to build a document around such fragments, which is tedious

Answer (score 15):

The command is `\lstinline`, not `\lstlinline`. If `{` and `}` pairs occur in the code, it's better to use the `\lstinline[...]!some code!` way.

The language etc. and other settings can be done in the optional argument. (the `language=C` setting is wrong for the given programming language -- it's not C, of course)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\lstinline[language=C]!while{$a || $b}!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for more general solution for multiple programming languages so I want to use "!" character as well.

Comment: @user3376620: Well, I answered your question before you put into a different direction :-(

Comment: Syntax: `\lstinline[⟨key=value list⟩]⟨character⟩⟨source code⟩⟨same character⟩` Also, I found experimentally that some engines support a wider working range of working <character> delimiters. For example, I found `¿` to work with `xelatex` and not with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @l --marc: Hm, how is this related to my answer? I used the correct syntax and usually users stick to the "!" character -- xelatex has never been an option to me. The fact that the user changed the question does not count

Comment: Does LaTeX has the convention that `!!` can be used as a substitution of `{}`?

Comment: @zyy: No, the `!!` style is a method to display verbatim content, i.e. text is displayed unexpanded, non-interpreted, e.g. `_` is displayed as underscore and not indicating a subscript. You could use `\lstinline+foo+` or `\lstinline?foo?` as well, but not `\lstinline{foo}` (as far as I remember)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think I used `\lstinline[language = {[LaTeX]TeX}]{\documentclass}` and it worked!